# Including user home dir in Jrebel.xml

Tags: jrebel

Using Jrebel with NetBeans 8.0.2, projects shared by multiple users. The root of the projects is variable "dev.env.home" defined as an ant variable in Netbeans settings. Is it possible to pass this variable to rebel.xml file?  I have tried this:

```
<dir name="${dev.env.home}\java\projects\Generator\target\classes"/>
```

But it does not seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try providing the value for that placeholder as JVM parameter.

-Ddev.env.home=C:\myhomedir

That should work.